# R dplyr subset rows that contain any character value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset in which a particular column (`x` in this case) has certain rows with character values.

How can I slice/subset these rows which contain any character value for data exploration purposes?

Please note that I don't want to hardcode all characters in rows to tell the code if the rows have these characters then subset these rows. Because my original dataset is huge, so this column could have any character values in any number of rows.

So, that is the purpose to see all those rows in that column that have a character value

Sample data and code:

```
library(dplyr)

x = c("1000", "1001", "1003", "14484R", "1004", "1005",  "12241alternet", "12634TAB", "12644R", "END", NA, NA)
y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)

df = data.frame(x, y)

# subset/slice rows in column x that contain any character value
```

Comment: Try `subset(df, is.na(as.numeric(x)) & !is.na(x))`

Comment: Yep, that works, but the code also returned a bunch of rows with `NAs` along with the rows that had character value(s). Why is that so sir?

Comment: that was the earlier code.  It should now return only non-NA elements.  The reason is that `is.na` returns `TRUE` for all NA elements, the `as.numeric(x)` converts to numeric and returns NA where there are non-numeric while leaving the NAs as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest would be to convert to numeric with `as.numeric`, which will return NA for all non-numeric elements, then use `is.na` to find the NA elements as a logical vector for `subset`ting (there would be a warning as part of the forced conversion to numeric)

```
subset(df, is.na(as.numeric(x)) & !is.na(x))
             x  y
4         14484R  4
7  12241alternet  7
8       12634TAB  8
9         12644R  9
10           END 10
```

The `& !is.na(x)` make sure that it drops all rows with `NA`s in the original 'x' column

Answer (score 5):

One option to capture any letters using `[:alpha:]`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% filter(str_detect(x, "[:alpha:]"))
              x  y
1        14484R  4
2 12241alternet  7
3      12634TAB  8
4        12644R  9
5           END 10
```

or since you said your dataset is huge:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[str_detect(x, "[:alpha:]")]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use base R and no packages :

```
df[grepl("[:a-z:]|[:A-Z:]", df$x),]
```

Comment: you should have `fixed = TRUE` and not `fixed(TRUE)`. The latter is from `stringr` package and not base R